# How can I find which controls are causing UI thread to spend most of its time doing layout?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, profiling

Using the *Application Timeline* performance profiler tool in Visual Studio 2017, how do I know which WPF controls are causing the UI thread to spend almost 100% of the time on layouting?

If I drill down in the timeline details I can see a `TextBlock` node but I can not figure out which control it refers to.

[image: UI thread utilization]

Answer (score 0):

Download the free **WPF Performance Suite** from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler).

The tool contains 2 components by default when installing:

1. **Perforator**: Displays the real-time GPU usage and the Frame rates, etc. Also has options to overlay the visually intensive elements!
   [image]
2. **Visual Profiler**: Shows the Visual Tree and the percentage time spent for each element inclusively and exclusively apart from the overall percentage of dispatcher and other lower level layers involved in the rendering and layout.
   [image]